# LinkedIn SDK init bad resultCode

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I'm following [this](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth) tutorial and everything seems fine until the LinkedIn app goes back to my Activity (in onResultActivity). I get a resultCode of 2, which I can't figure out what it means. This resultCode is also not handled within the LinkedIn sdk code!

Has anyone come across this? Or had it run successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result code "2" indicated an error is occurring.  You should be able to see more information about the problem from the `errorInfo` and `errorDesc` objects returned.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm getting the following errors..."errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST",
    "errorMessage": "either bundle id or package name \/ hash are invalid, unknown, malformed" I don't understand what I'm doing wrong though!

Comment: Have you configured your package name and hash values in the LinkedIn application configuration as is outlined in the documentation? https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk#application

Comment: I only did it for my debug key. Is it a must that I do it for my release key in order for it to work?

Comment: You only need to do it for the debug key during development.  I would suggest the next step is to double-check the values and make sure they've been calculated correctly.

Comment: FYI, I'm getting the same error with the sample app!!

Comment: I am getting this error too. Who find the solution? plz tell me

Comment: I`m facing this issue too!

Answer (score 2):

Try this way I got my solution with this process of creating SHA

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());

            // writtenToFile("FB_KEY_HASH.txt",
            // Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
            // Base64.DEFAULT).toString(), false);

            if (AppUtills.showLogs)
                Log.v(pageName,
                        "KeyHash:"
                                + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                                        Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My problem was when generating the debug key I thought the password prompt was for me to password protect the debug.keystore file. Actually it is prompting you for the password that Android studio used when creating the file which is android. If you put in the wrong password the keytool -exportcert command returns no errors. However if you try keytool -list ~/.android/debug.keystore it will let you know if the password is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while integrating linkedin in android app. This error is due to invalid hash key.Generate key hash either by development keystore aand release keystore.

Development Keystore Syntax :  keytool -exportcert -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

It will prompt for password : give password android
you will get correct keyhash.